Cognito auth flow ERROR while creating SIGN UP/LOGIN with AWS amplify & ReactApp
I have created a Cognito User Pool and App Client in the AWS Educate program's AWS environment (Builder Lab). After setting up these resources, I am attempting to integrate AWS Amplify with my React application. However, I am encountering an issue where the configuration appears correct, but I am still receiving an error.
Steps Taken:

I created a Cognito User Pool and App Client in AWS Cognito.
I created a new React app using create-react-app.
I installed the required dependencies, including aws-amplify and
@aws-amplify/ui-react.
I set up the awsconfig object with the correct values, including the User Pool ID and Web Client ID.
I used Amplify.configure() in my React app, passing the
configuration object.

Error:
Despite these steps, I am receiving the following error in the browser console:
Uncaught TypeError: this.resourcesConfig.Auth.Cognito is undefined
    at notifyOAuthListener (Amplify.ts:63)
    at configure (Amplify.ts:41)
    at configure (initSingleton.ts:41)
    at App.js:8
    at factory (react refresh:6)

What I’ve Observed:
The awsconfig object appears to be correctly populated, and I see the appropriate values for userPoolId and userPoolWebClientId in the console log.
The issue persists despite checking all configurations in the AWS console and ensuring that the Amplify.configure() is called with the correct configuration object.
Question:
What could be causing the error "this.resourcesConfig.Auth.Cognito is undefined" in my React app, even though I have correctly set up the AWS Cognito User Pool and App Client, and my awsconfig object looks fine?
Object { Auth: {…} }
​
Auth: Object { userPoolId: "mypoolId", userPoolWebClientId: "myclientId" }
I use Authenticator CODE from the https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/, and in my awsExports I added userpoolId and appClientId...
import React from 'react';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import awsExports from './Configuration';

console.log(awsExports);

Amplify.configure(awsExports);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}

const awsExports  = {
    Auth:{
        'userPoolId':'us-east-1_6UjYQhWiT',
        'userPoolWebClientId':'6npe3oagri6ofa2cb0no3u8eo7'
    }
}

export default awsExports;

